# What's the English term for setter positions in volleyball?

Tags: terminology, volleyball

When speaking about the positioning system in volleyball in German, we usually say the word "Läufer" (lit. "runner") and append the number, *X*, of the position of the setter, to refer to a certain position in the positioning system. All other players automatically know where to go.

What is the English equivalent for this "Läufer *X*" phrase?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only thing I've ever used is something like "The setter's at 4" or whatever - although I'd expect that if you're playing at a level where you've got designated roles, people should know where they are on court.

Comment: Imagine a training situation, where the coach asks the players to line up with the setter on 4. In German, this fact, that the setter is at 4, is described as "Läufer 4." If someone somehow's forgotten at which position he is at, he asks "Welchen Läufer haben wir?" (verbatim: "Which runner do we have?"). Curious that apparently there is no similar term in English.

Answer (score 0):

In England they say either setter @ X or P X ie P4.

In American they use Row X but it’s different to P. I believe row 1 is P6, row 2 is P5, row 3 is P4 etc